# Curious for a second-opinion: Would this answer pass review?

Tags: discussion, answers

Got this in the review stack and though it was pretty borderline.  The question asks about a basic implementation of applying an acceleration based on a key press.  Here's the [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/50077/25768):

> you need to make the acceleration happens over time (per game tick)
>   gradually.
>
> you need to time the acceleration in such that every N seconds, it
>   make your character moves faster until a limit is reached.
>
> your while statement make it happen in a single tick, it make no
>   difference than assigning X = 1.

It does very little to answer the question, and it's not written in a manner that's very readable, but it is technically answering the question and there is *some* guidance there about the correct approach (though very little assistance on implementation).  Would this answer pass review for you?

Comment: At the very least it should be edited for grammar.

Comment: @Tetrad, my grammar correction is pending.  But beyond that?

Comment: I rarely delete answers unless its spam or not an answer at all, so I'm pretty lenient when it comes to that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After obvious edits, I'd call it done. A *bad answer* is still *an answer*.

As for how I'd vote:

- If there are existing and clearly better answers, I'd downvote for unhelpfulness and explain with a comment.
- Else I'd simply not vote. It's not directly harmful, but neither is it directly helpful.